# How do I put a folder with java files into eclipse's package explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, file, package, explorer

I have downloaded a folder with 15 to 20 .java files in it, I want to put this folder in eclipse's package explorer. How can I do so? I'm using eclipse indigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new project in Eclipse:

```
File > New > Java Project
```

This will create a project with a `src` folder.  Then copy and paste the Java files into this directory via the file system.  If the .java files are packaged you may need to create packages within the `src` folder.

```
Click the src Folder > File > New > Package
```